# Material in render different to Material showing up in the IndexMA pass

Tags: materials, masking, render-passes, id-mask

I am trying to create a mask based on materials having certain nodes. In this case I want to filter any shader that uses the Glass BDSF Node, I have this object with a couple of different materials as show below:

[image]

I want to have this glass on this cabinet drawer to be picked up by the mask so I give it a pass index of 1 as seen below:

[image]

The layout of my compositor:

[image]

This set up outputs a blank mask.

While if I set the pass index of the material "wood_furniture_dresser" to 1 and the material "dresser_glass" to 0 the output is:

[image]

This creates a mask that covers both the wood and glass even though the glass is a separate material. Is there any way to have a mask with **just**
the glass?

I would appreciate any help you can give me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: As of 2.8x we have cryptomatte, ID masks are crappy to work with.

Comment: Tried the cryptomatte node and used the dropper to select the material from properties and unfortunately this does not fix the problem